# A question on op amp selection in an active filter

Tags: operational-amplifier, active-filter

Below is a Sallen-key type active LPF which filters out all the ac components and integrates(averages) the incoming 1kHz 1V pulse train.

[image]

There are tools to design these filters, but my question is about the op amp part:

If I change this op amp with any other single supply op amp in LTspice I get totally different results. I must say Im not into details of op amps and active filters so please answer as to a beginner.

Why is any generic op amp doesn't work for this circuit?
What determines us to choose this particular op amp here?
What is so special about LM358 here?

**Edit:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to put an offset on your input, or use a dual supply op amp

Comment: What amount of offset and why?

Comment: Vcc/2, for a start.  Look at the data sheet for the op amp you select, and look at the allowable range of common-mode input range.  If its an "idealish" rail to rail on the input, the voltage on the input terminals can't go above or below the rails.

Comment: i was expecting a more informative explanation.

Comment: Many op amps that are rail to rail on the input only allow inputs that are, say, 150mV of the lower rail.

Comment: See my edit is that the parameters causing this?

Comment: I don't know what "this" is, unless you show us outputs for corresponding inputs for different, but specific, part numbers, but I'm talking about the common mode input range.  However, your issues might indeed be caused by the output range.  "Rail-to-Rail" can refer to the inputs, the outputs, or both.  I've been bitten by this myself.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you mean by "totally different results" from the other op-amp. Readers shouldn't have to dig through comments to understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

The LM358 works with inputs that can range from 0 volts (negative supply rail) to Vcc-1.5 volts and, this corresponds with the signal you are feeding the circuit so no problem there. The LM358 output also works pretty much down to 0 volts so there shouldn't be any problem there either.

So, if you tried a different op-amp and it didn't appear to work correctly it's highly likely that its inputs and output do not get close to 0 volts. Not many do but rail-to-rail op-amps can be fairly well relied upon to do what they say on the tin.

Alternatively power the op-amp with a +/- supply and then everything should be fine.

Comment: Lets focus on single supply operation only. "it's highly likely that its inputs and output do not get close to 0 volts." Could you explain what do you mean by that? Does that mean they might have very large input offset voltage? which parameter in data sheet should i look for if i need to replace LM358?

Comment: As an example I for example tried LT1677  CAN BE USED Single Supply and it is rail to rail 
Op Amp which doesnt work. It has even much lower input offset voltage than LM358. But I dont get what is happening.

Comment: Common mode input voltage range is the parameter. Input offset voltage is something different entirely and relates to how slightly different the two inputs are in terms of there being an inherent offset between the two. Output range is the other parameter.

Comment: being rail-to-rail, common-mode input voltage range, output range. besides these keywords i cannot relate these and underatnd whats happening inside.

Comment: You say "I get totally different results" and "Why is any generic op amp doesn't work for this circuit?" - what do you get? Show what you get with the LT1677 please.

Comment: When I learn about opamps lets say non inverting op amp gain. Texts show a generic opamp symbol and show the gain as 1+R1/R2. And when I replace any opamp I get same gain in LTspice. But in this case when I learn about active filters the texts again uses a generic opmap symbol as if it works for all op amps but in this case no MOST do not work only a few. And I cannot find any explanation.

Comment: To your specific question for example with LT1677 I get the output as 630mV for 1V pulse input. For 100mV pulse input I get 133mV and with LM358 I get 66mV.  LT1677  has less input offset voltage still outputs 133mV for an input of 100mV 50% duty cycle pulse. Obviously it doesn't integrate correctly.

Comment: Please also see my edit. Are you talking about those parameters? Is that my problem?

Comment: The edit brings up the difference for sure - but it's only relevant for the small input voltages. The circuit doesn't integrate BTW, it filters and without a picture of things there can be no further assistance. All I can say is try a small negative rail to see if things then become clearer and try and find an op-amp that has a lower output swing towards 0 volts (if you need a single supply).

Comment: When I made GND -1V for LT1677 output was still 133mV but when I lowered it to -2V it worked fine the output became like 54mV as expected. Does that indicate the issue was Vol of the output swing?

Comment: Maybe the signal at the non-inverting input wants to go a little bit below 0 volts in the normal operation of filtering. Check that out. It's hard to say without a proper screen shot of the sim.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is counter-intuitive, but a low pass active filter requires an op amp with good high-frequency response.  You are actively filtering out the high frequency (via C1) and many (most?) newer op amps are low power with correspondingly low bandwidth.  These will be poor choices for active filters, when filtering signals with high frequency components (like square waves).  Check the gain-bandwidth product (sometimes listed as unity-gain bandwidth).